# The blog binding in my Azure functions fails with "No binding parameter exists for ..."

Tags: azure, binding, azure-functions

I have a C# Azure function.

```
  [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("my-queue")]MyClass item
        , [Blob("report-streams/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream reportStream)
    {
```

but I get the error:

```
 Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'MyFunction.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No binding parameter exists for 'name'.
```

Ideally I would like to bind name to the property item.Id but did not find a solution.

Comment: can you try `[Blob("report-streams/{Id}", FileAccess.Write)]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think this is directly possible. However, you should be able to achieve this using binding at runtime. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#single-attribute-example

```
string id = item.id;// retrieve here from your item
using (var writer = binder.Bind<TextWriter>(new BlobAttribute(
                $"report-streams/{id}", FileAccess.Write)))
    {
        writer.Write("Hello World!");
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Function supports binding the [Trigger metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#trigger-metadata) as input parameters in C#. And the properties include the Id. So just bind the id with {Id} in the input path, then it will work. The below is my test.

```
         public static void Run(
            [QueueTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, 
            [Blob("blobcontainer/{Id}", FileAccess.Write)]Stream reportStream,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
```

This is the queue with the id.

[image]

This is the function console output and the blob container output.

[image]

[image]

Hope this could help you.